# Zipalign Issue with -f Flag

Tags: apk, zip

I'm attempting to sift through a folder of .apks, and zipalign them

I have the latest ADT

My command lies in a bash script, that loops through the folder

and my zipalign command is: `zipalign -f 4 my.apk my.apk`

It keeps popping `Input and output can't be the same file`

My understanding is (from the ADT docs), is that this is supposed to be possible.

Now, when I try `zipalign -f 4 my.apk` instead of zipaligning them, it simply gives me the help info for zipalign.

What gives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use

```
zipalign -f -v 4 my.apk output.apk
```

Do remember that if you zipalign before you sign, the signing will undo the alignment.

Comment: right but shouldnt the -f flag overwrite the original?

Comment: @o7thWebDesign no, it says in the online documentation that -f overwrites any existing output.apk